# Sub-vector of matrix with column indices given by vector

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix A which looks like this:

```
 A = [ 5 6 ; 7 8; 9 10 ]

 A =

 5     6
 7     8
 9    10
```

and then a vector e which indicates which column I want to select for each row:

```
e = [ 1 ; 2 ; 1]
```

with the interpretation that from row 1 of A I want to select the 1st column; from row 2 the 2nd; and from row 3 again the 1st.

I thought I would do

```
A(e)
```

which gives

```
A(e)

ans =

 5
 7
 5
```

whereas what I want to obtain is

```
 5
 8
 9
```

How can I do this most efficiently? My actual matrix contains almost 1 million rows, so a for loop is not an option. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two options.

MATLAB's sub2ind to convert from row & column subscript indexing to linear indices:

```
linear_indices = sub2ind(size(A), (1:size(A,1))', e);
A(linear_indices)
```

Calculating the same on your own:

```
linear_indices = (1:size(A,1))' + (e-1)*size(A,1);
A(linear_indices)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a straightforward way to do it with `arrayfun` that takes 2 arguments : line index from 1 to 3 and column index `e`

```
arrayfun( @(i,j) A(i,j) , (1:size(A,1))' , e )
```

Comment: I haven't done any performance checks, but I guess this solution will also be rather slow?

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer is doing the same thing as @marsei 's excellent answer, but I'll add this anyway for completeness:

```
A = [ 5 6 ; 7 8; 9 10 ];
e = [ 1 ; 2 ; 1];

for i=1:length(e)
    B(i)=A(i,e(i));
end
```

```
>> B

B =

     5     8     9
```

Note that this returns a row vector, so would also need to be transposed with `B'`, or by pre-allocating before the loop with `B=nan(size(e));`.

Comment: Thank you, but I was asking specificallly for a solution without a loop due to matrix size in my actual use case.

Comment: No worries - just thought I'd add it for completeness. I've been surprised before how efficient looping can be in Matlab compared to matrix ops, for example.